# What type parameters would an innerclass and interface have in the following situation?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose we have a generic class that implements a generic interface like this

GenericClass.java

```
public class GenericClass<T> implements GenericInterface<T> {

    private class AnotherClass<T> {
        T aVariable;
    }

    @Override
    public T aMethod() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

GenericInterface.java

```
public interface GenericInterface<T> {
    T aMethod();
}
```

What would be the type parameter passed on in the interface? Also, what would be the type parameter passed to the nested class inside GenericClass.

Comment: I don't understand you question here. Are you asking what `T` is?

Comment: I mean, it's in the name `generic`, it can be any class. What class will you pass depends just on you.

Comment: If I create a new instance of GenericClass like this: new GenericClass<Integer> then will the interface it implements also be GenericInterface<Integer> and will the inner class als be AnotherClass<Integer>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take your comment as the actual question:

> If I create a new instance of GenericClass like this: new GenericClass then will the interface it implements also be GenericInterface and will the inner class als be AnotherClass

Yes, it's gonna be `GenericInterface<Integer>`. No, it's not gonna be `AnotherClass<Integer>`.

`class GenericClass<T>` introduces a type-parameter `T` that can be used e.g. with a generic `interface` like you do. **Now be careful:** `class AnotherClass<T>` that is nested within `GenericClass` introduces *another* type-parameter `T` that *hides* the one that `GenericClass` has introduced.

If you want `AnotherClass` to use `T` of `GenericClass`, then simply skip the `<T>` for `AnotherClass`.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the type parameter passed on in the interface?

The one given on the `GenericClass` declaration.

E.g. if you have `new GenericClass<Integer>()`, then the interface would be `GenericInterface<Integer>`.

> What would be the type parameter passed to the nested class inside GenericClass.

The one given on the `AnotherClass` declaration.

E.g. if you have `new AnotherClass<String>()`, then `aVariable` would have type `String`. That is true even if the outer class is a `GenericClass<Integer>`.

If you use a good IDE, then it would likely tell you that the `T` for `AnotherClass` is *hiding* the `T` for `GenericClass`.

Comment: It’s also worth mentioning that If he would remove the type parameter of the inner class, T would refer to the Type Parameter of its parent class, as long as the inner class is not static